# Setter gives an error using TypeScript in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, jsx

I'm creating a small todo app in TypeScript with React. However i'm getting an error when i want to add a todo to my todolist. i'm guessing i have the setter function wrong and i need to add Dispatch and setStateAction. Unfortunately i'm just learning TypeScript and would like to know what i'm doing wrong.

Thanks for your help!

```
import React, { Dispatch, SetStateAction, useState, useContext } from "react";

import { FormWrapper } from "./Style";
import { TodoContext } from "../../context/TodoContext";

interface Todo {}

function Form({}: Todo) {
  const [todo, setTodo] = useState<string | undefined>(undefined);
  const [todos, setTodos] = useContext(TodoContext);

  const submitHandler = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    setTodos({ id: todos.length + 1, label: todo });
    setTodo("");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <FormWrapper>
        <form action="" onSubmit={(e) => submitHandler(e)}>
          <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="Todo" />
          <input
            type="submit"
            placeholder="Add todo"
            value={todo}
            onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void =>
              setTodo(e.target.value)
            }
          />
        </form>
      </FormWrapper>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Form;
```

I was trying to add a todo to my todolist.

Comment: It would be useful if you also added what error you're getting.

Comment: The error is: Argument of type '{ id: number; label: string | undefined; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<Todo[]>'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'id' does not exist in type 'SetStateAction<Todo[]>'.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your `setTodos` is a setter for an array of `Todo` objects.

In that case, you probably want to add an extra Todo to that array, and you can do that e.g. with:

```
setTodos((prevTodos) => {
  const newTodo = {
    id: prevTodos.length + 1,
    label: todo
  };
  return [
    ...prevTodos,
    newTodo
  ];
});
```